# RequestFactory: read only properties on domain object/proxies?

Tags: gwt, getter-setter, requestfactory

I have `Document` entity having read-only (from client perspective) property `modificationAuthor` (I want it to be modified only on server side which is aware of currently logged user). `Document` entity has has no setters for `modificationAuthor` property neither in proxy nor in domain object.

The problem is that it's not a simple property but other entity (`User`) so I need to add `modificationAuthor` to the `paths` when I invoke `requestFactory.find(id).with(paths).fire()` to get `Document` instance. (so that `modificationAuthor` is not null when I want to read it from `Document`).

But after adding it to paths and trying to persist `Document` object I'm getting exception: `Could not locate setter for property modificationAuthor...`. It seems that RF requires setters even for properties that are designed to be read-only.

Is there currently any way to avoid adding setters to such properties and be able to read it and persist parent object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a side-effect of [issue 5952](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5952), which will (should) be fixed in GWT 2.5, to be released in a month or so: RF erroneously thinks the `modificationAuthor` property has been modified (because it fails at comparing the User entity with itself), so it sends an *operation* to the server for that property, and the server then tries to set the property value to the given entity (which happens to be the one that's already there).

In the mean time, I'm afraid you'll have to add a dummy setter (it does not need to actually assign the property value) to your `Document` domain object.